# Create serial based on 2 columns PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with 2 columns, one has a gid (serial) with intended duplicate values, I need them like that, and another column with a number, I need a 3rd column ("serial" in blue in the image) that looks like that.
A serial number for each different "gid" but with the series from the "count" column

[image]

I tried row_number () over (partition by count order by gid) but I dont' get the correct results

EDIT: As Gordon Linoff says, I tried that and i get this results, not working as expected...
[image]

EDIT2: It works, I just needed to order the row_number, but this alters the rest columns of my table, would be any way to make row_number work in order since beggining wthout needing to order later?

EDIT3: Actually, it works perfectly, the display was wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want both `gid` and `count` in the `partition by`:

```
select row_number () over (partition by gid, count order by gid)
```

You might have something more meaningful for the `order by` clause, if you have additional columns.